# How to add TRoleAuth attribute at method level in C++ Builder?

Tags: delphi, authentication, c++builder, datasnap

In Embarcadero's documentation, the following example can be found for Delphi:

```
TServerMethods1 = class(TComponent)
public
  [TRoleAuth('admin')]
  function EchoString(Value: string): string;
  function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
end;
```

I cannot find an equivalent example for C++ Builder.

How can I add the `TRoleAuth` attribute at method level in C++Builder when developing for DataSnap REST?

Comment: It is declared for C++ Builder, but [here is a note](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Attributes_and_RTTI), _Delphi attributes are not supported in C++Builder_, so maybe it's not possible. But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: if you can't use them, just code the onUserAuthorise Event of your DSAuthenticationManager to always return True. I can use them in Delphi, and I do that anyway.